# How to gather web site usage statistics without degrade the performance?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, statistics, capacity-planning

In order to be able of understand how the users are using a web application, which are the parts of the application with more stress and all that, I need to keep data about how the site is being used in a queryable way.

I would like to keep general data like:

- Requester IP address
- URL
- HTTP web method
- Request body length (if POST)
- Response body length.
- Request content type.
- Response content type.
- time that the operation has spent in total
- time that the operation has spent in the DB
- etc..

And also more precise data about internals cache hit/miss, special conditions, etc...

When you have just one server, and if the application is not big, a text file could do the trick. But if the amount of information is big, and/or you have several servers, another approach is needed, since you would like to merge this data.

What is the best approach in the ASP.NET world?

- Using a database? sql or nosql? would you use fire-and-forget asynchronous calls?
- Using a specialized monitoring application?
- Do you queue/buffer the log entries? how?
- Do you use custom performance counters?

Thanks.

Comment: To not degrade the performance, just take the month bandwidth and divide it with the total users from the iis log. Or else, the body length is one think, what about the images length ? don't you count them ?

Comment: Also if you have application, and not a series of page, actually ONE to TREE page is doing all the work... or almost one, this is the stress you looking for. Then sql profiler can show you more, and c sharp profiler also.

Comment: To understand how users use your application, stay behind a user :) and Osbert him with out speaking  :) This data gives you no so useful knowledge about how user use your application. Even if you know that a user needs 82k data read compressed 2.5m uncompressed, send back 10k on post back ones a day, and see 10 pages, what you do about ?